# How to find a document in mongoose and return the last 10 days from array of objects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to `findOne` document and return the last 10 days of objects in this document array. The `schema` is this one:

```
const CurrenciesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    currency: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    exchange_rate: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    spread: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        default: 0,
        select: false
    },
    lastUpdate: {
        type: Date
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    history: [
        {
            date: Date,
            rate: Number
        }
    ]
});
```

I'm trying to query a specific currency and return the objects from the `history` array from the last 10 days.

My `query` is this one:

```
async rateHistory(req) {
        try {
            const date = moment().subtract(10, "days");
            return await Currencies.findOne({
                currency: req.params.id,
                history: {
                    $elemMatch: {
                        date: { $gte: date._d }
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (e) {
            return new Error(e);
        }
    }
```

However, when I run this code, it returns the correct currency but all `history` array.

What am I missing?

Edit: I also tried this:

```
async rateHistory(req) {
        try {
            const date = moment().subtract(10, "days");
            return await Currencies.aggregate(
                { $match: { currency: req.params.id } },
                { $unwind: "$history" },
                { $match: { "history.date": { $gte: date._d } } }
            );
        } catch (e) {
            return new Error(e);
        }
    }
```

But this doesn't return anything

Answer (score 0):

I found the right way to make the query:

```
async rateHistory(req) {
        try {
            const date = moment().subtract(10, "days");
            return await Currencies.aggregate([
                {
                    $match: { currency: req.params.id }
                }
            ])
                .unwind("history")
                .match({ "history.date": { $gte: date._d } });
        } catch (e) {
            return new Error(e);
        }
    }
```